# Can't put JSON output into CSV format with jq

Tags: json, csv, jq, flatten

I'm building a list of AWS EBS volumes attributes so I can store it as CSV in a variable, using jq. I'm going to output the variable to a spread sheet.

The first command gives the values I'm looking for using jq:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes | jq -r '.Volumes[] | .VolumeId, .AvailabilityZone, .Attachments[].InstanceId, .Attachments[].State, (.Tags // [] | from_entries.Name)'
```

Gives output that I want like this:

```
MIAPRBcdm0002_test_instance
vol-0105a1678373ae440
us-east-1c
i-0403bef9c0f6062e6
attached
MIAPRBcdwb00000_app1_vpc
vol-0d6048ec6b2b6f1a4
us-east-1c
MIAPRBcdwb00001 /carbon
vol-0cfcc6e164d91f42f
us-east-1c
i-0403bef9c0f6062e6
attached
```

However, if I put it into CSV format so I can output the variable to a spread sheet, the command blows up and doesn't work:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes | jq -r '.Volumes[] | .VolumeId, .AvailabilityZone, .Attachments[].InstanceId, .Attachments[].State, (.Tags // [] | from_entries.Name)| @csv'
jq: error (at <stdin>:4418): string ("vol-743d1234") cannot be csv-formatted, only array
```

Even putting the top level of the JSON into CSV format fails for EBS volumes:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes | jq -r '.Volumes[].VolumeId | @csv'
jq: error (at <stdin>:4418): string ("vol-743d1234") cannot be csv-formatted, only array
```

Here is the [AWS EBS Volumes JSON FILE](https://gist.github.com/bluethundr/786ded200aee380e9bb9831af505437b) that I am working with, with these commands (the file has been cleaned of company identifiers, but is valid json).

How can I get this json into CSV format using jq?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only apply `@csv` over an array content, just enclose your filter within a `[..]` as below

```
jq -r '[.Volumes[] | .VolumeId, .AvailabilityZone, .Attachments[].InstanceId, .Attachments[].State, (.Tags // [] | from_entries.Name)]|@csv'
```

Using the above might still retain the quotes, so using `join()` would also be appropriate here

```
jq -r '[.Volumes[] | .VolumeId, .AvailabilityZone, .Attachments[].InstanceId, .Attachments[].State, (.Tags // [] | from_entries.Name)] | join(",")'
```

Answer (score 2):

The [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53754835/5025060) resolves another obscure jq error:

> string ("xxx") cannot be csv-formatted, only array

In my case I did not want the ***entire*** output of jq, but rather each Elastic Search *document* I supplied to jq to be printed as a CSV string on a line of its own.  To accomplish this I simply ***moved the brackets to enclose only the items to be included on each line***.

First, by placing my brackets only around items to be included on each line of output, I produced:

```
jq -r '.hits.hits[]._source | [.syscheck.path, .syscheck.size_after]'
[
  "/etc/group-",
  "783"
]
[
  "/etc/gshadow-",
  "640"
]
[
  "/etc/group",
  "795"
]
[
  "/etc/gshadow",
  "652"
]
[
  "/etc/ssh/sshd_config",
  "3940"
]
```

Piping this to `| @csv` prints each document's values of .syscheck.path and .syscheck.size_after, quoted and comma-separated, on a separate line:

```
$ jq -r '.hits.hits[]._source | [.syscheck.path, .syscheck.size_after] | @csv'
"/etc/group-","783"
"/etc/gshadow-","640"
"/etc/group","795"
"/etc/gshadow","652"
"/etc/ssh/sshd_config","3940"
```

Or to omit quotation marks, following the pattern noted in the accepted Answer:

```
$ jq -r '.hits.hits[]._source | [.syscheck.path, .syscheck.size_after] | join(",")'
/etc/group-,783
/etc/gshadow-,640
/etc/group,795
/etc/gshadow,652
/etc/ssh/sshd_config,3940
```